# Determining the Maximum Distance Between a Polygon and Line in ArcMap

Tags: coordinates, distance, arcgis, proximity, arcmap

I am using ArcMap to determine the maximum distance from a set of polylines (fault lines in Virginia) to a set of polygons (sinkholes in Virginia).

I have tried using some tools in the Proximity toolset but have had no luck.

My initial try used the "Near" tool, but I was not able to produce an output attribute table field with 'feet' as my linear coordinate. It kept producing outputs in 'angular degrees,' which I am having trouble converting back into linear feet.

Then I tried using the "Euclidean Distance" tool but this did not have an option to input both the sinkholes and the fault lines, so the results was basically a multiple ring buffer raster around the faults.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The Near tool seems like the right choice. Here is a quote from the [Near tool help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000001q000000):

> When using the PLANAR option for the Method parameter, the input features should be in a projection that is appropriate for distance measurement, such as an equidistant projection.

Therefore, you have two possible solutions:

- Project your input feature class from its geographic spatial reference to a projected spatial reference (for example, the right UTM or State Plane projection for that region). The output units will be the units of the input feature class's spatial reference.
- Use the `GEODESIC` method instead of `PLANAR`. The output units will be meters, which you can convert to feet quite easily using the Field Calculator.